# ln how manyways can we distribute $7$ apples and $6$ oranges among $4$ children so that each child gets at least one apple.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> In how many ways can we distribute $7$ apples and $6$ oranges among $4$ children so that each child gets at least one apple?

I think this can be solved by using permutations because the word distribute (arrange) is given, if the word select (e.g., select a group of ..) was there I was to use combinations.
Also permutations takes into consideration the order of arrangement. Am I right? Can some one explain how to solve the above problem?

Comment: Find the number of ways to distribute the apples, using Stars and Bars. Find the number of ways to distribute the oranges, using Stars and Bars. Multiply.

Comment: @AndréNicolas stars and bars????

Comment: Please see [this Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29)

Comment: @AndréNicolas okay,thanks :)

Comment: anyone any other answer?

Comment: Hint: The oranges can be distributed in $\binom{9}{3}$ ways.

Comment: @AndréNicolas There are only 6 oranges

Comment: Yes, I know. Look at the Stars and Bars article.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Tommorow is my exam,i have seen that.But my teacher have not taught the stars and bars stuff.Could you help me do it using the c&p formulate.I know the answer will be right in any way but,the examiner's POV i will lose marks

Comment: The number of ways to distribute $n$ identical objects to $k$ people with everybody getting at least one is $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$. If we omit the restriction of at least one, the number of ways is $\binom{n+k=1}{k-1}$. This is done in detail in the reference, also in sevral MSE questions.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks let me see those

Comment: Note the typo above, one of the expressions should be $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$.

Comment: okay..Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

The strategy mentioned by Andre Nicolas is also called as Balls in Urns Principle.

Suppose you have *k* distinguishable urns and *n* indistinguishable balls,there are $\dbinom{n+k-1}{k}$ ways of arranging the balls in urns.

Also,$\dbinom{n+k-1}{n}$ = $\dbinom{n+k-1}{k-1}$,which you can easily verify.

In the given question,there are 4 distinguishable children,3 indistinguishable apples and 6 indistinguishable oranges.Since every child has to have a apple,you have no choice over 4 apples.

Hence,there are $\dbinom{3+4-1}{4-1}$ ways of choosing apples and $\dbinom{6+4-1}{4-1}$ ways of choosing oranges.

Using the multiplication principle,there are $\dbinom{3+4-1}{4-1}$*$\dbinom{6+4-1}{4-1}$ of doing them together.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Give each child their required 1 apple. Thus all you actually have to do is distribute 6 oranges and the remaining 3 apples among the 4 children. Consider each fruit separately, then multiply.

Comment: okay,so let me consider the case of distributing 6 oranges to 4 children.I understand that permutations does takes into consideration the order of distribution.So cannot use i use 6P3 here right?,Please clear my doubts here